# Unable to drop database user without login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, users, logins

One of our developers with blanket privilege on a database wanted to create a regular user mapped to a login when what he mistakenly created was a user without login and now I'm unable to remove the user. `DROP USER XX` command runs forever with no result nor an error. The user doesn't own any schemas as well. How can I remove this user?
Thank you

Comment: what you are getting the error?

Comment: "command runs forever with no result nor an error"

Comment: Do you have "ALTER ANY USER permission on the database of that user".

Comment: I hope this isn't a production db that a developer has 'blanket' permissions on. Hearing that anywhere makes me choke on my morning coffee.

Comment: I'm SA. It's UAT.

Comment: Try to run `EXEC sp_change_users_login 'report'` to see all orphan users.

Comment: It's not an "orphan user". It's of type "user without login". They are different things.

Comment: Just checking, have you been able to verify that user has not been granted ownership of any objects, i can't replicate behavior, if user has permissions i get errors otherwise it just drops instantly...

Comment: There is no object in the database which is associated with this user.

Answer (score -2):

Check for any blocking `SPID`s when you have issued the `DROP USER XXX` command.

Then kill.